# Enable TLS 1.2 for .Net 4.5 app in Docker

Tags: asp.net, docker, tls1.2, windows-container

Can we enable TLS1.2 when we containerize an asp.net app which currently uses .Net framework 4.5 running in windows server 2008? I heard TLS 1.2 is only available from .Net 4.7

Comment: There are a *LOT* of duplicate questions already. Why are you using an unsupported OS like Windows 2008 though? And why such an old runtime? You have to patch the OS and write extra code to enable TLS1.2. If you used a supported OS and .NET 4.7, TLS 1.2 would work out of the box

Comment: Thank you for your response. We don't to change the code, but lift and shift the legacy app - containerize in windows container 2019 and still use .Net 4.5. Will the application break if we enable TLS1.2 in this case?

Comment: I repeat, there are a *lot* of duplicate questions already. If you don't want to change the code, you'll have to target .NET 4.7. In fact, even 4.5 is out of support. The earliest supported version is 4.5.2. The first version that supported TLS1.2 out-off-the-box was 4.6 but people go directly to 4.7 to avoid issues with .NET Standard 2.0 compatibility

Comment: Even if you think you use 4.5, you are *not*. .NET 4.x runtimes are binary replacements. This means that installing a newer version replaces the older one. Windows 2019 comes with .NET 4.7.2. Since you're going to run on 4.7.2 anyway, why not change the project's target framework as well?